# Adding several apps to INSTALLED_APPS at once

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-apps

I am working on an app, which requires another app to be installed. I can add it to my setup.py and it will install the other app too.

After installing my application, i need to add it to INSTALLED_APPS, but i need to add the external app too.

Is there a way to pass the other application implicitly?

What's the recommended way to handle that kind of dependency to avoid asking the users to add more than one app when it is required?

Comment: Your question is not so clear to me. If you need to add an app name to `INSTALLED_APPS`, then just add it in the settings.py file, right? Why other users can add apps to your project?

Comment: i mean, i would need to add 'my_app', but my_app requires some other external app, so i would need to add it too. My question is if there is a way to add the second one implicitly.

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS` is a tuple in the settings.py file, you can add as many apps as you want. For example, mine looks like INSTALLED_APPS = ('south', 'mptt', 'guardian', 'tastypie', ....) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#installed-apps

Comment: You can use [django-autoconfig](https://github.com/mikebryant/django-autoconfig) to achieve exactly this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without doing some strange hacking, there's no way to do this, nor should there be. The user should be aware of what they are adding to their project and what dependancies are required. Remember [Django's design philosophy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/misc/design-philosophies/#explicit-is-better-than-implicit):

> Explicit is better than implicit

Have a look at some of the following apps. They all require dependancies in the `INSTALLED_APPS`. They make it clear in the docs that the user has to add them to their project manually:

- [Django Zinnia](http://docs.django-blog-zinnia.com/en/latest/getting-started/install.html)
- [Django Admin2](http://django-admin2.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installation.html)
- [Django Filer](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer)
- [Django Filebrowser](https://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#installation)

Comment: Yeah, was just curious if there was a decent alternative to achieve that xD

Answer (score 2):

There is a library called [django-autoconfig](https://django-autoconfig.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that lets you do this. You basically include an `autoconfig.py` in your app, and if your app is include in `INSTALLED_APPS`, it's `autoconfig.py` is loaded.

The file should look something like this:

```
SETTINGS = {
    'INSTALLED_APPS': [
        'external_app_1',
        'external_app_2',
    ],
}
```

Read the docs for more information about ordering and more advanced stuff like that.

Comment: It does sound nice, however it requires extra settings on user project. What i would like is some way to do without forcing the users of my app to add any other dependency.